# How to create a function that can sort an array in bash?

Tags: bash, function

I'm trying to figure out how to make a function that can take an array as a parameter and sort it. I think it is done with positional variables, but I'm not sure.

Comment: An array of what, sorted by which condition? Did you try anything yourself? Do you want to output the result? Sort in place?

Comment: It will sort an array of 20 numbers between a range of 1 and 100. Yes I would like the result echoed. The sorted result does not have to be stored just outputted I guess "in place".

Comment: If you output the result, you don't sort in place. In place means, that the original array is modified which will influence other usages of the array.

Comment: It really doesn't need to do anything else besides be sorted, and echoed.

Comment: Here's a function, written in bash, that sorts arrays: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30576368/3979290

Comment: Related (on [ubuntu.se]): [Display a sorted array](https://askubuntu.com/questions/859905/display-a-sorted-array)

Comment: Bash is really not the right tool for the job here... Please use Python for this type of thing instead. [Google agrees](https://google.github.io/styleguide/shell.xml?showone=When_to_use_Shell#When_to_use_Shell).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sort the easy way with `sort`, `tr`:

```
arr=($(for i in {0..9}; do echo $((RANDOM%100)); done))
echo ${arr[*]}| tr " " "\n" | sort -n | tr "\n" " "
```

Into a new array:

```
arr2=($(echo ${arr[*]}| tr " " "\n" | sort -n))
```

Without help by `tr`/`sort`, for example bubblesort:

```
#!/bin/bash    
sort () {
    for ((i=0; i <= $((${#arr[@]} - 2)); ++i))
    do
        for ((j=((i + 1)); j <= ((${#arr[@]} - 1)); ++j))
        do
            if [[ ${arr[i]} -gt ${arr[j]} ]]
            then
                # echo $i $j ${arr[i]} ${arr[j]}
                tmp=${arr[i]}
                arr[i]=${arr[j]}
                arr[j]=$tmp         
            fi
        done
    done
}
# arr=(6 5 68 43 82 60 45 19 78 95)
arr=($(for i in {0..9}; do echo $((RANDOM%100)); done))
echo ${arr[@]}
sort ${arr[@]}
echo ${arr[@]}
```

For 20 numbers, bubblesort might be sufficient.

Comment: I think your answers helped me the best thank you.

Comment: And your solution unfortunately depends on `seq`. For bash just use arith for loops……

Comment: @userunknown right.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Please provide your own answer, if you have a better  solution. I'm working fine most of the time with 'echo', not 'printf' and tr, not paste. I don't like to answer questions for code which I woulnd't have written.

Comment: A tr-less solution: `IFS=$'\n'; echo "${arr[*]}"`.

Answer (score 11):

#### bash

I don't think `bash` has any builtin support for that yet. Options would be to implement a sort algorithm by hand or to invoke `sort` to do the sorting.

If we consider that array elements can contain any byte value but 0 in `bash`, to do it reliably, we'd need to pass the list of elements NUL-delimited and use the `-z` option to `sort` (non-standard but available in GNU sort or FreeBSD sort).

bash-4.4 (released September 2016) makes it easier as it introduced a `-d` option to its `readarray` builtin to specify the delimiter.

To sort array `a` into array `b`:

```
readarray -td '' b < <(printf '%s\0' "${a[@]}" | sort -z)
```

would sort the array reliably. Use the `-n`, `-r` options to `sort` to sort numerically or in reverse (or any sort criteria supported by `sort`).

To implement your `sortarray` function (sorts all the arrays passed by-name as arguments):

```
sortarray() for array do
  eval '((${#'"$array"'[@]} <= 1))' || readarray -td '' "$array" < <(
    eval "printf '%s\0' \"\${$array[@]}\" | sort -z")
done
```

With earlier versions of `bash`, you can use `read -d` in a loop to achieve the same:

```
b=()
while IFS= read -rd '' item; do b+=("$item"); done < <(
  printf '%s\0' "${a[@]}" | sort -z)
```

For the `sortarray` function:

```
sortarray() for array do eval '
  tmp=()
  while IFS= read -rd "" item; do tmp+=("$item"); done < <(
    printf "%s\0" "${'"$array"'[@]}" | sort -z)
  '"$array"'=("${tmp[@]}")'
done
```

#### zsh

Zsh has builtin support to sort arrays.

you can use the `o` parameter expansion flag to sort lexically (`O` for reverse order). You can add the `n` flag to sort numerically:

```
$ a=('' 12 2 d é f $'a\nb')
$ printf '<%s>\n' "${(@o)a}"
<>
<12>
<2>
<a
b>
<d>
<é>
<f>
$ printf '<%s>\n' "${(@no)a}"
<>
<2>
<12>
<a
b>
<d>
<é>
<f>
```

In locales that don't already sort case-independently, you can also add the `i` flag for that.

To assign to an array:

```
b=("${(@o)a}")
```

So a `sortarray` function would be like:

```
sortarray() for array do eval "$array=(\"\${(@o)$array}\")"; done
```

#### AT&T ksh (ksh88 or ksh93, both of which can be found as sh on some systems)

```
set -s -- "${a[@]}"
b=("$@")
```

`set -s` sorts the list of arguments and stores it in the positional parameters. The order is lexical.

A `sortarray` function could be:

```
sortarray() for array do
  eval 'set -s -- "${'"$array"'[@]}"; '"$array"'=("$@")'
done
```

Comment: For `zsh` the option `n` does a numeric sort of numbers in a string. It will do a lexicographical sort of the strings prefixing the number, followed by a numeric sort. This is handy for stuff like `foo1 foo02 foo3`. However, for a pure numeric string, this will fail when negative numbers are in use. `a=( 10 8 -20 100 ); echo "${(@n)a}"` this returns `8 10 100 -20`. Be aware that the sorting of floats is just mimicked. It just does a numeric sort on the fractional part. You can see this with this example `a=(1 1.11 1.2); echo ${(n)a}` this returns `1 1.2 1.11` because `2 < 11`

Answer (score 5):

```
sortnums(){
    local OLDPWD IFS=' /'
    cd -- "$(mktemp -d)" || return
    touch -- $*;  ls -A
    cd - >/dev/null &&
    rm -rf -- "$OLDPWD"
}
```

Here's a slightly more complicated, and somewhat slower version which nevertheless does not squeeze duplicates and which sorts *(reasonably sized)* decimal numbers in numeric order - though *(space-split)* other strings are still sorted, string length is considered first. And to handle generic strings you'd almost definitely want to set the `g=[0-9]` glob differently.

I'll be honest - I would *(maybe)* consider sorting a list of *words* or *numbers* like this, but it wouldn't otherwise occur to me to create a file with a name that wouldn't at least fit comfortably within a paragraph. And so it splits on spaces. Most often, that's the right thing to do. It is, however, also hampered by a sanity requirement of treating `/` like a null. But it was just for fun, anyway, really.

```
fs_sort(){
        local OLDPWD IFS=' /' opt="$-" g
        cd -- "$(mktemp -d)" || return
        set     -C                         ### noClobber for testable >
        for     g in    $*                 ### disallow any / reference
        do      until   command >" $g"     ### who needs dot glob?
                do      g=" $g"            ### '   1' lex== ' 1'
        done;   done    2>&1               ### -C is bitchy
                g=[0-9]                    ### now glob the array
        while   set -f *\ $g   &&          ### set it  &&
                <"$1" g+=? arr+=( $* )     ### <chk && (clean) it
        do      set +f;    done 2>&1       ### clear it
        set +fC "-${opts:--}"              ### put stuff where we found it
        cd - && rm  -rf -- "$OLDPWD"       ### don't leave our trash out
}       >/dev/null                         ### cd - is chatty
```

If there's any lesson in this, maybe it should be what a filthy thing bash arrays are in the first place. If data was simply kept in *files* we'd never have any issue `sort`ing it in the first place. Imagine how much easier it would be to maintain important shell state when necessary if your login shells just grabbed themselves a tiny chunk of *tmpfs* at startup, copied a `~/.sh` directory into it, and then copied back any files you may have marked sticky since at shutdown. *All* of your state *names* would sort as simply as `set *`, and their contents would be accessible to any utility you wanted to call on them as is any other file.

Comment: @don_crissti - yes, it will sort in lexicographic order. oh - i thought the default was `-d`. i'll fix that - good thing i stuck in the `|| return` in the first place. the asker doesnt specify a numeric sort, just that he has numbers which should be sorted *(and im aware of how stupid that sounds)*. the only issues any of that should cause is `1 10 2 3 4` and so on. that is *very* easily handled with `ls -A|sort -n`, of course *(and would likely be a quicker way to do it than just `printf %s\n "$@"|sort -n` for any sizeable set *(maybe?)*. anyway, making them filenames means you can do `a=(*)`

Answer (score 5):

Two weird, in-memory plain-bash solutions. Benchmark for many answers given in this question is available on [gists](https://gist.github.com/Artoria2e5/5694c113912a43fbdef1#file-sorttime-bash), with results available in the comment area. I may update those things with copypastes from new answers irregularly.

All the complexity calculations ignore the length of strings in bash. For `index_sort` there may be a lot of `atol` and its reverse, linear to strlen and log to int value; for `alias_sort`, `strcmp` is linear.

### `index_sort` for unsigned int64

Bash always prints an indexed array in numerical order.

**Minimum Bash Version**: 2.0
**Algorithm Type**: Insertion Sort on a Linked List, non-inplace
**Time Complexity**: O(*n*^2), best O(*k***n*) (adaptive via *lastref* since 4.3) 
**Space Complexity**: O(*n*)
**Source Reference**: [array.c:array_insert@4.3](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/array.c?id=ac50fba#n654)

```
# index_sort <source_arr> [target_arr:-source_arr]
index_sort() {
  # Not that surprising: using indirect expansions in a `for` loop is slow.
  local _tmp=() _src="$1[@]" _sorted_nodup _sorted; _src=("${!_src}")
  for i in "${_src[@]}"; do (( _tmp[i]++ )); done
  # This eats duplicates.
  _sorted_nodup=( "${!_tmp[@]}" )
  # The numeric values in _sorted_nodup<int, int> gives us the occurrence of 
  # the element in the original sequence.. takes extra 1~4x time to expand.
  # The extra time decreases as elems decreases, -> ~1.2x.
  # CONSIDER SKIPPING THIS and use `_sorted_nodup` for the final eval instead.
  for i in "${_sorted_nodup[@]}"; do
    j=${_tmp[i]}
    while ((j--)); do _sorted+=("$i"); done
  done
  # Assign it back..
  eval "${2:-$1}=(" '"${_sorted[@]}" )'
}
index_sort arr out
declare -p out
```

Since most people believe that procedures running as carefully-optimized native code should be much faster than those as interpreted scripts, the coefficient for *n*^2 should be quite low compared to the rest of the expression.

### `alias_sort` for strings (byte-lexicographical)

Bash always prints aliases in lexicographical order. This idea came from mikeserv, I only wrapped it into a function. This one contains a subshell as command substitution (necessary for alias env scoping).

**Minimum Bash Version**: 1.14.7 (any version with a sorting `alias`)
**Algorithm Type**: `qsort` with `strcmp`
**Time Complexity**: O(*n* log *n*)
**Space Complexity**: O(*n* log *n*)
**Source Reference**: [alias.c:all_aliases@1.14.7](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/alias.c?id=726f63884db0132f01745f1fb4465e6621088ccf#n241), [alias.c:legal_alias_name@3.0](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/general.c?id=b80f6443b6b7b620c7272664c66ecb0b120a0998#n245)

```
# alias_sort <source_arr> [target_arr:-source_arr]
# modified to fit in a function.
alias_sort(){
  local _s=() _e="$1[@]" IFS=$'\n' # does bash 1 support indirect expansion?
  _s=($(
    unalias -a &&                  # clear all aliases
    alias "${!_e/%/=}" &&          # (exp: map append '=') pass to alias
    alias                          # sort (see src) and print the aliases
  )) || return
  _s=("${_s[@]#alias }")           # strip off the `alias '
  # strip the shortest trailing =* and assign back.
  eval "${2:-$1}=("'"${_s[@]%=*}")'
}
```

Notes:

1. This implementation eats duplicates. Looking for a not-too-clumsy solution. Additionally, this slows down a lot with duplicates on bash, perhaps the internal alias hashtable is unhappy.
2. Since bash 3.0, `alias` checks the alias names, and this breaks everything with non-aliasable things. Using a temporary intermediate array, say, `_g` for doing `_g=("${_e/some/replace}") _g="${_g[@]/more/...}"` for escaping should still be fast enough, but I am too lazy to list out all those bad characters now. `` /* [\\'"`$<>[:space:]] */ ``

Comment: kind of all of the stuff is. i thought about that too - `export -p` and `set` and `alias`.  but it involved a lot of parsing i didnt want to do, and so i just made a blank directory. i dont use bash arrays though and so it didnt occur to me - its a pretty good answer - a lot less parsing than i would have wound up doing with that other stuff.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas It appears it's my fault.. My memory got wrong. Let me try some indexed array though -- perhaps with number-indexed ones I can still get sorted output.

Comment: ok, but im curious - can you tell me how these compare?

Comment: im not surprised about the sort being slow - `bash` doesn't tend to do anything efficiently. but it only makes me more curious about your benchmarks *results*.

Comment: @mikeserv time for 128, 1024 and 65536 elems added to comment area.

Comment: yeah! sortnums is *slow*. yours is pretty good. i figured out how to do it with `alias` like `eval "unalias -a; alias $(printf "%d= "  "$@" 2>/dev/null); alias" | cut -d= -f1` - i think that should work *(but in `bash` you might need `set -o posix` first)* - it will eat dups, though, of course.

Comment: oh! i didnt notice the Cygwin thing - i dont think it works as a good control system for benching anything *but* native shell apps. cygwin does this weird file-system abstraction layer, and doesn't have a true analog for a unix fork. i'll try it too.

Comment: @mikeserv retried test with 65536 elems on bash 4.3.27 (JuiceSSH, Android). Ran declare -p and it appears to me that those are still sorted. One possible theory is that this might be added since a specific bash version as a way to accelerate sequential array access (with *lastref*). I will check the git log.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32764/discussion-between-arthur2e5-and-mikeserv).

Comment: i think probably it is unhappy. it is the only shell that refuses to handle aliases according to spec in a script without enabling some obscure shell option anyway, as far as i am aware.

Comment: your gist has gone 404...

Answer (score 1):

```
#! /bin/bash

array=('2' '7' '5' '9' '0')
sort=0
echo ${array[@]}
len=${#array[@]}
echo $len


for ((i=0; i<$len; i++))
do
    for((j=i+1; j<$len; j++))
    do
        if [ ${array[i]} -le ${array[j]} ]
        then
            continue
        else
            sort=${array[i]}
            array[i]=${array[j]}
            array[j]=$sort
        fi
    done
done
echo ${array[@]}
```

Answer (score 0):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7442417/how-to-sort-an-array-in-bash) looks closely related.

Here's a plain old mergesort, without external processes, variable namespace tricks or aliasing tricks:

```bsh
mergesort() {
  local -n -r input_reference="$1"
  local -n output_reference="$2"
  local -r -i size="${#input_reference[@]}"
  local merge previous
  local -a -i runs indices
  local -i index previous_idx merged_idx \
           run_a_idx run_a_stop \
           run_b_idx run_b_stop

  output_reference=("${input_reference[@]}")
  if ((size == 0)); then return; fi

  previous="${output_reference[0]}"
  runs=(0)
  for ((index = 0;;)) do
    for ((++index;; ++index)); do
      if ((index >= size)); then break 2; fi
      if [[ "${output_reference[index]}" < "$previous" ]]; then break; fi
      previous="${output_reference[index]}"
    done
    previous="${output_reference[index]}"
    runs+=(index)
  done
  runs+=(size)

  while (("${#runs[@]}" > 2)); do
    indices=("${!runs[@]}")
    merge=("${output_reference[@]}")
    for ((index = 0; index < "${#indices[@]}" - 2; index += 2)); do
      merged_idx=runs[indices[index]]
      run_a_idx=merged_idx
      previous_idx=indices[$((index + 1))]
      run_a_stop=runs[previous_idx]
      run_b_idx=runs[previous_idx]
      run_b_stop=runs[indices[$((index + 2))]]
      unset runs[previous_idx]
      while ((run_a_idx < run_a_stop && run_b_idx < run_b_stop)); do
        if [[ "${merge[run_a_idx]}" < "${merge[run_b_idx]}" ]]; then
          output_reference[merged_idx++]="${merge[run_a_idx++]}"
        else
          output_reference[merged_idx++]="${merge[run_b_idx++]}"
        fi
      done
      while ((run_a_idx < run_a_stop)); do
        output_reference[merged_idx++]="${merge[run_a_idx++]}"
      done
      while ((run_b_idx < run_b_stop)); do
        output_reference[merged_idx++]="${merge[run_b_idx++]}"
      done
    done
  done
}

declare -ar input=({z..a}{z..a})
declare -a output

mergesort input output

echo "${input[@]}"
echo "${output[@]}"
```